# How to use \csname to call a command with an argument?

Tags: macros, csname

I have a function that redefines the trig functions given so that

```
\cos[2]{\frac{1}{2}}
```

and

```
\cos^2\!\pqty{\frac{1}{2}}
```

look just like this in the end:

[image: code result]

, where I used `\pqty` (from the `physics` package) to have the automatic scaling for what's in the brackets. I created these commands to do this:

```
\newcommand{\makeold}[1]{
    \expandafter\let\csname old#1\expandafter\endcsname \csname#1\endcsname
}%This makes it so that \makeold{cos} would call \let\oldcos\cos

\newcommand{\changetrig}[1]{
    \makeold{#1}

    \expandafter\renewcommand\csname#1\endcsname[2][]
    {\qopname\relax o{#1}
    \ifx\relax##1\relax\else^{##1}\fi\!\pqty{##2}}
}
```

and this works just fine when I call `\changetrig{cos}`. However, I wanted to add functionality so that it would also call `\renewcommand\arccos\cos[-1]` in this command if `\changetrig{cos}` were to be called.
But adding this within my `\changetrig` command

```
\expandafter\renewcommand\csname arc#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname#1\endcsname[-1]
```

does not work at all. What have I missed in my addition?

Edit: I realized my example code at the top did not match my picture, and I forgot to mention relevant packages.

Comment: it is hard to understand your question if you post fragments that can not be tested, and that use commands for which you do not give a definition, but if `#1` is `cos` `\expandafter\renewcommand\csname arc#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname#1\endcsname[-1]` is `\renewcommand\arccos\cos[-1]` which is missing `{}` I assume you want  `\renewcommand\arccos{\cos[-1]}` (using square brackets seems a bit strange but I (think?) you want them typeset not an optional argument?) so `\expandafter\renewcommand\csname arc#1\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\csname#1\endcsname[-1]}`

Comment: I provided all of the code in the `\changetrig` definition at the bottom. I used square brackets because it is an optional argument (without the argument, it has no exponent for the trig function as in the command). But thank you! The code worked. I have to ask though, why was the `\expandafter` necessary with the {}s?

Comment: Glad you got it working but... I can not understand you code at all, you provided no test file and haven't defined many of the commands used, `pqty` for example, `\cos` doesn't take an argument so I would expect `\cos[-1]` to typeset as `cos [-1]` not be interpreted as an optional argument but you may have other definitions. You need `\expandafter{\csname` to expand the `\csname after the `{`. Please always provide code as a single complete test document that shows the problem and can be used to test answers.

Comment: All of this code is in the preamble and doesn’t require any extra code. The only code missing was  `\usepackage{physics}`, which I acknowledged in my edit of the post. My changetrig command changes cos so that it takes an optional argument, as in the post and my reply to your comment. And thank you for the explanation!

Comment: the comment about undefined commands was before you edited it (or before I noticed the edit) but even as it is now, posting code in fragments like this makes it much harder to edit. A test file is much easier and saves guessing how the fragments should be reconstructed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `#1` is `cos`  then you want to construct

```
\renewcommand\arccos{\cos[-1]}
```

so

```
\expandafter\renewcommand\csname arc#1\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\csname#1\endcsname[-1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If so many `\csname`..`\endcsname` confuse you, you can use them under the hood via
a `{`-delimited macro like `\MakeTokenFromCsname`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\makeatletter
%%
%% \MakeTokenFromCsname<stuff not nested in braces and without braces>{Csname}
%%    ->
%% <stuff not nested in braces and without braces>\Csname
%%
%% E.g.,  
%%
%%   \MakeTokenFromCsname\foo{bar} -> \foo\bar
%%   \MakeTokenFromCsname{bar} -> \bar
%%   \MakeTokenFromCsname\let\foo={bar} -> \let\foo=\bar
%%   \MakeTokenFromCsname\MakeTokenFromCsname\let{foo}={bar} 
%%      -> \MakeTokenFromCsname\let\foo={bar} 
%%      -> \let\foo=\bar
%%
%% \MakeTokenFromCsname requires the triggering of _two_ expansion-steps/_two_
%% "hits" by \expandafter to deliver the result.
%%
\@ifdefinable\MakeTokenFromCsname{%
  \long\def\MakeTokenFromCsname#1#{%
    \romannumeral0\@MakeTokenFromCsname{#1}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\@MakeTokenFromCsname[2]{%
  \expandafter\@@@MakeTokenFromCsname\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}%
}%
\newcommand\@@@MakeTokenFromCsname[2]{#2#1}%
\makeatother

\newcommand{\changetrig}[1]{%
  \MakeTokenFromCsname\MakeTokenFromCsname{@ifdefinable}{old#1}{%
    \MakeTokenFromCsname\MakeTokenFromCsname\LetLtxMacro{old#1}{#1}%
  }%
  \MakeTokenFromCsname\DeclareRobustCommand{#1}[2][]{%
    \qopname\relax o{#1}%
    \ifx\relax##1\relax\else^{##1}\fi\!\pqty{##2}%
  }%
  \MakeTokenFromCsname
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\renewcommand
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{arc#1}%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\MakeTokenFromCsname{#1}[-1]}%
}

\changetrig{cos}

\show\oldcos
\show\cos
\show\arccos

\begin{document}

$\oldcos^{2}\!\pqty{\frac{1}{2}}$

$\cos[2]{\frac{1}{2}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]